# Call external Web API in SharePoint online using SharePoint framework

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, spfx, azure, azure-ad

I have published Web API from Visual Studio 2017 in Azure portal and I want to consume those data in SharePoint online.

I have created one SPFx project file from node js and opened in Visual Studio code, Now I want to call the Web API from SharePoint framework.

I am new here please post some link and comments. How is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the AadHttpClient in SPFx. It's well documented here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/use-aadhttpclient-enterpriseapi

Comment: i went through above url and found they are using Azure function , I want to consume webapi data not azure function? can you please help to differentiate? whether can we use azure function api in webapi ? and how to use to consume webapi in framework

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery getscript method for calling external API in SharePoint environment. In your spfx webpart code,  install jQuery - npm i jQuery and use the following code snippet to call your external API.

```
$.getScript("test.js")
  .done(( script, textStatus )=> {
    console.log( textStatus );
  })
  .fail(( jqxhr, settings, exception )=> {
    console.log("Triggered ajaxError handler.");
});
```